Google AppSheet - OData connection
I'm trying to integrate my Google AppSheet app with my own data from the Odoo CRM. But because the tables are very complex and also not on internet access and the application offer it's own API I wanted to use AppSheet OData.
For the beggining I was trying to integrate with a test environment offered here: https://www.odata.org/odata-services/service-usages/trippin-advanced-usages/
Still when I complete Add OData connection information with

OData Service Root URL: https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(3mslpb2bc0k5ufk24olpghzx))
Username: RandomData
Password: RandomData
SAP Gateway: No
CSRF Required: No

The TEST seems fine but when I Authorize Access I receive:
404: Page not found
The page you're looking for isn't here. Try checking the URL again or head back to the homepage.

Have to say that I only know Python, I found a OData library but is 8 years no change.
And also testing with Postman it shows fine:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(3mslpb2bc0k5ufk24olpghzx))/$metadata",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "People",
            "kind": "EntitySet",
            "url": "People"
        },
     ...
}

Thank you much
